# In Excel, Is there a way to count populated cells, post a specific word in a cell?

Tags: excel, count

I'm trying to count how many cells are populated in a row, to the right of the word "OUT".

This is to calculate the number of consecutive years played, without manually doing so, or without losing history.

Eg:

Each year populates it's own cell, as does each piece of information such as name, total years played and consecutive years.

Name(A) : Total Years Played(B) : Consecutive Years(C) : History(D:Z)

Ryan :  5 : 1 :  2008   2009    OUT 2012    2013    OUT 2015

Thanks in advance

Mark

Comment: Sorry, I tried to be concise, but missed that.  To the right of the Last OUT

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data in `D2:Z2`, the following array formula (confirmed with `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`)

```
=LOOKUP(23,FREQUENCY(IF(D2:Z2<>"",COLUMN(D2:Z2)),IF((D2:Z2="OUT"),COLUMN(D2:Z2))))
```

calculates number of nonempty cells to the right of last `OUT` word. 
If there's no `OUT` word, returns total number of nonempty cells.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is perfect.  I just can't work out the 23?

Comment: @M.Howard Any number higher than maximum number of `OUT` words is OK to make sure `LOOKUP` returns last entry in array returned by `FREQUENCY`. You can even set it to maximum literal value `9.99999999999999E+307`.

Comment: Ahh thanks for that clarification, that makes even more sense to me now